# Limit wp-rest-api posts request to an array of postID's

Tags: wordpress, rest, include

My complete project will need to return the ***nearest-posts*** to the ***given geolocation***.

I succeeded in doing this by building a custom callback function seeking the nearest posts but also building a custom array containing the data-fields of those nearest posts. If I define this function as the callback function of my route all works great!

All ok but I would like the return to be a copy of the default post-return, of course limited to the nearest posts. And not a set of custom defined fields.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Before going into details I would like to know which way to go. My plan, that doesn't work, was :

- extend WP_REST_Posts_Controller

  - register (and initialize) a new route
  - define a custom callback function in this new route
  - the custom callback function builds an array of `postID`'s that are the  nearest (*lat&long* was passed in the *http request*)

So far so good but now comes my problem. 
How do I pass the array of `postID`s to the `get_items` method of `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` in order to get a "*default*" return of specific(nearest) posts

Clearly a simple approach like this doesn't work

```
public function custom_callback_function($geoloc_array) {

    // call the function get_nearest_items($geoloc_array) 
    // that returns an array of postIDs'  
    // something like  : [163,49]

    $nearest_poi_array = get_nearest_items($geoloc_array);

    // put the array of postIDs to fetch in "include" of a new array
    // hand over new array to the get_items method of WP_REST_posts_controller

    $posts_to_return['include'] = $nearest_poi_array;
    return get_items($posts_to_return);

}
```

If somebody could point me to the right direction I would be grateful!!